# HTML input file with accept attr hangs when browsing folder with many files

Tags: javascript, html, file, google-chrome, input

I am developing a file picker for MMS messages, which accept a limited number of MIME types or extensions.

When I click browse (**Mac**, Chrome 60 and Chrome Canary 61, Firefox, Safari) my last folder is opened with a system file-picker, where it should gray out non-accepted files.

It happens that my test folder is Downloads, which now has something around 600 files or different types. It is important that folder contains different file types, as on a different folder, which only has .png it's all okay.

File picker (and browser) 'hangs', from first glance. Actually it unhangs after one-two (sic!) minutes with a list of files as described above.

Did anyone encounter this? Ways to fix it?

**Only Mac issue.**
On Windows 10 did not see the same problem, everything works smoothly.

```js
var accept = ['image/jpeg',
  'image/png',
  'image/bmp',
  'image/gif',
  'image/tiff',
  'image/svg',
  'video/3gpp',
  'video/mp4',
  'video/mpeg',
  'video/msvideo',
  'audio/mpeg',
  'text/vcard',
  'application/zip',
  'application/rtf',
  'application/gzip'
];

var accepted_extensions = ['.jpg'].concat(accept
  .map(function(item) {
    return '.' + item.split('\/')[1];
  }));

document.querySelector('input.mime')
  .accept = accept.join(',');

document.querySelector('input.ext')
  .accept = accepted_extensions.join(',');
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Accept for MIME types</label>
  <input type="file" class="mime" multiple />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Accept for extensions</label>
  <input type="file" class="ext" multiple />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Without Accept property</label>
  <input type="file" multiple />
</div>
```

(Demo: http://jsbin.com/zowixof/edit?js,output)

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a programming issue more of a hardware one. With over 600 files in the directory, your computer is probably just lagging behind as it tries to populate the explorer window (assuming your using windows).

Comment: On my computer it works without issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performed bisect search on my test folder, and it appeared that all the slowness was caused by one Djvu file.

The related tickets discussions are:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/djvu/bugs/278/
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7789107?start=0&tstart=0 (possibly contains solution, but didn't help me)